# iOS In App Purchases: Objective-C vs. Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm planning on creating an app for the iPad that will require In-App Purchases. This will be my first foray into programming for iOS, although I have developed in Java for Android, including using Google's In-App Billing APIs. Would I be better off using Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Both Swift and Objective-C have the exact same set of libraries, so that shouldn't factor into your decision. Swift is the newer language, and there is a chance that Obj-C will start being deprecated (I really hope not). However, right now, there is still much more on the internet about Obj-C than Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to answer you what should you do, you should figuure that out yourself.

There are much more tutorials for In app purchaces for Obj C out there, but there are already many for Swift, so that shouldn't be a problem.

[Here is one I find very good](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-tutorial-set-integrate-app-purchases/)

Also, Apple made a very good job with their Swift Book, and you have everything explained there.
You can find it on iBooks, it's free

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do your app in Swift (which is better to understand if you have already programmed in Java, in my opinion), use Swift

If you want to do your app in Objective-C well... use Objective-C, note that there is many more resources/tutoriel for In-App purchases in Objective-C than in Swift

It's up to you !